# How to access endpoint without token in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using an actuator for getting server health, also I am doing validation on the token on each request, now I need to put a token to access actuator health but `I want to access actuator health without using the token` and without affecting API endpoint with token!

Note: My Actuator working fine with the token.

also, I implement the OncePerRequestFilter class for validating the firebase token for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `SecurityConfiguration` where you permit access to actuator requests:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http     
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        
    }

}
```

You may want to read the [spring-boot-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html) for more information.

---

EDIT:
When using `OncePerRequestFilter` you could implement the `shouldNotFilter` method and check for actuator paths there:

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request)
  throws ServletException {
    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    return path.startsWith("/actuator");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, eol for your response, I tried this before its not working, i implemented OncePerRequestFilter for validating each request token , if token is missing,i am getting token is missing.

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer regarding `OncePerRequestFilter`.